# Why does NSColor.controlTextColor change according to background color?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nscolor

I'm working on a Cocoa application and I find that as long as the font color of `NSTextField` is set to `NSColor.controlTextColor`, the font will change according to the background color of `NSTextField`.

For example, when I set the background color to white, the font becomes black.

But when I set the background color to black, the font turns white.

I want to define an `NSColor` to achieve the same effect. How to achieve it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's implemented on a rather low level in the drawing methods of the NSView (sub)classes. If you are talking about the dark mode in Mojave you can define different colors for light and dark in the image assets.

Comment: `labelColor`, and many other system colors, are now *dynamic* colors; they change depending on the appearance mode of the view/window/screen/system. I suspect you'd have to create your own subclass of NSColor to achieve a similar effect, and I would venture that this would be a non-trivial task.

Comment: @JamesBucanek Yes, it's a totally clueless job for me. So I want to see if anyone else knows something about this job and can give me some help.

Comment: Are you just looking to change a color for Dark vs Light modes of macOS? Or are you trying to determine given a particular background color whether you should display a different color? The former is easy, the latter, not so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass in any color and then determine which text color would be more ideal - black or white - you first need to determine the **luminance** of that color (in sRGB). We can do that by converting to grayscale, and then checking the contrast with black vs white.

Check out this neat extension that does so:

```
extension NSColor {

    /// Determine the sRGB luminance value by converting to grayscale. Returns a floating point value between 0 (black) and 1 (white).
    func luminance() -> CGFloat {
        var colors: [CGFloat] = [redComponent, greenComponent, blueComponent].map({ value in
            if value <= 0.03928 {
                return value / 12.92
            } else {
                return pow((value + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4)
            }
        })
        let red = colors[0] * 0.2126
        let green = colors[1] * 0.7152
        let blue = colors[2] * 0.0722
        return red + green + blue
    }

    func contrast(with color: NSColor) -> CGFloat {
        return (self.luminance() + 0.05) / (color.luminance() + 0.05)
    }

}
```

Now we can determine whether we should use black or white as our text by checking the contrast between our background color with black and comparing it to the contrast with white.

```
// Background color for whatever UI component you want.
let backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.8, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
// Contrast of that color w/ black.
let blackContrast = backgroundColor.contrast(with: NSColor.black.usingColorSpace(NSColorSpace.sRGB)!)
// Contrast of that color with white.
let whiteContrast = backgroundColor.contrast(with: NSColor.white.usingColorSpace(NSColorSpace.sRGB)!)
// Ideal color of the text, based on which has the greater contrast.
let textColor: NSColor = blackContrast > whiteContrast ? .black : .white
```

In this case above, the `backgroundColor` produces a contrast of `10.595052467245562` with black and `0.5045263079640744` with white. So clearly, we should use black as our font color!

The value for black can be corroborated [here](https://contrast-ratio.com/#black-on-rgb%28127.5%2C%20204%2C%2051%29).

---

**EDIT:** The logic for the `.controlTextColor` is going to be beneath the surface of the API that Apple provides and beyond me. It has to do with the user's preferences, etc. and may operate on views during runtime (i.e. by setting `.controlTextColor`, you might be flagging a view to check for which `textColor` is more legible during runtime and applying it).

**TL;DR: I don't think you have the ability to achieve the same effect as `.controlTextColor` with an `NSColor` subclass.**

Here's an example of a subclassed element that uses its `backgroundColor` to determine the `textColor`, however, to achieve that same effect. Depending on what `backgroundColor` you apply to the class, the `textColor` will be determined by it.

```
class ContrastTextField: NSTextField {

    override var textColor: NSColor? {
        set {}
        get {
            if let background = self.layer?.backgroundColor {
                let color = NSColor(cgColor: background)!.usingColorSpace(NSColorSpace.sRGB)!
                let blackContrast = color.contrast(with: NSColor.black.usingColorSpace(NSColorSpace.sRGB)!)
                let whiteContrast = color.contrast(with: NSColor.white.usingColorSpace(NSColorSpace.sRGB)!)
                return blackContrast > whiteContrast ? .black : .white
            }
            return NSColor.black
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can implement with:

```
let textField = ContrastTextField()
textField.wantsLayer = true
textField.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
textField.stringValue = "test"
```

Will set your `textColor` depending on the `layer`'s background.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Maybe I didn't make it clear. In fact, I wanted to ask how to make my NSColor inheritance classes achieve such color adaptation. That is, I wanted to understand how NSColor works.

Comment: You want an NSColor subclass that does the above ? What is it you're trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing a subclass of NSColor. As I said earlier, I want to reduce the amount of code I code and apply the color I want to display when a control loses focus or gains focus. Just like the picture.

Comment: In that case, it seems like you'd want to subclass the control itself. NSColor objects will only be the color you define them as.

Comment: Edited the answer above with the best possible solution, imho